# Basis of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

$$\text{let }v_1=
 \begin{bmatrix}
    1   \\
    1 \\
    -1 \\
    1   
  \end{bmatrix} , v_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
    -1   \\
    1 \\
    1 \\
    -1   
  \end{bmatrix} v_3 = \begin{bmatrix}
    1   \\
    -3 \\
    -1 \\
    2   
  \end{bmatrix} v_4 = \begin{bmatrix}
    1   \\
    -2 \\
    -1 \\
    3   
  \end{bmatrix} v_5 = \begin{bmatrix}
    1   \\
    2 \\
    0 \\
    3   
  \end{bmatrix} \text{ Find a subset of}
$$

$v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4, v_5$ that form a basis for $sp(v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4, v_5)$

## My solution:

What I did is I row reduced and got

$$
 \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 3/2 & 0  \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 5/2 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1   
  \end{bmatrix}
$$

My final answer is the basis is $\{v_1, v_2, v_3, v_5\}$

Because I think the basis is like the column space and there is a pivot in those columns. Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Because I think the basis is like the column space and there is a pivot in those columns.

I'm not really sure what you mean by *"is like the columns space"*, but your method is fine.

> What I did is I row reduced and got
>
> $$
>  \begin{bmatrix}
>     1 & 0 & 0 & \color{blue}{3/2} & 0  \\
>     0 & 1 & 0 & \color{blue}{5/2} & 0 \\
>     0 & 0 & 1 & \color{blue}{2} & 0 \\
>     0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1   
>   \end{bmatrix}
> $$
>
> My final answer is the basis is $\{v_1, v_2, v_3, v_5\}$

That's correct. You can interpret the fourth column as follows:
$$v_4 = \color{blue}{\tfrac{3}{2}}v_1+\color{blue}{\tfrac{5}{2}}v_2+\color{blue}{2}v_3$$